# facets as in facet_grid, and axis.line as for facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am trying to build a plot using facets as in [facet-grid](/questions/tagged/facet-grid), so plots separate in the x and y axes using two factors, as with:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) + 
  facet_grid(cyl ~ gear, scales="free") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(size=0.5))
```

[image]

The problem with the above approach is that only axis lines are shown for the up and left-most plots, so it is difficult to differentiate plots without using a colored `panel.background`.

This problem does not occur with [facet-wrap](/questions/tagged/facet-wrap), but this function will apparently not group factors in the two axes, or the strips will be always in one of the sides (according to `strip.position` argument), but not up and right as for `facet_grid`. e.g.:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
  facet_wrap(cyl ~ gear, scales="free") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(size=0.5))
```

[image]

**Question**
Is it possible to create a plot with `facet_grid`, but lines in all axes, or alternatively use `facet_wrap`, but group factors as with `facet_grid`?

Comment: Can you please add some visual examples / plots? Maybe that would be of help to some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `facet_rep_grid` in the `lemon` package. Here is the code to produce the desired plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lemon)

mtcars %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, 
                 y=wt)) + 
  facet_rep_grid(cyl ~ gear, 
                 scales="free",
                 repeat.tick.labels = "all") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.5))
```

[image: Plot lemon rep]